# Correct way to get filtered data from CoreData to populate UITableView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm saving Data in Entity and attributes are String amount, String category, Date date and String subCategory and now I want to get last month info from `CoreData` and than populate my `UITableView`.
My code looks like this:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Outcome>(entityName: "Outcome")
        let startDate = Date().startOfMonth()
        let endDate = Date().endOfMonth()
        let sort = NSPredicate(format: "date => %@ && date <= %@" , startDate as NSDate, endDate as NSDate)
        fetchRequest.predicate = sort
        do {
            self.outcomes = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch {
            print("Cannot fetch Expenses")
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
```

startDate and endDate are from Date() extention:

```
extension Date {    
    func startOfMonth() -> Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(from: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: self)))!
    }

    func endOfMonth() -> Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(month: 1, day: -1), to: self.startOfMonth())!
    }
}


extension FirstViewController{
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return outcomes.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OutcomeTableViewCell") as? OutcomeTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
    let outcome = outcomes[indexPath.row]
    cell.configureCell(outcome: outcome)
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return .none
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (rowAction, indexPath) in
        self.removeItem(atIndexPath: indexPath)
        self.fetchCoreDataObjects()
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.1491314173, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
    return [deleteAction]
}
```

}

So I ended up with empty `UITableView` and I have no idea why.
Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: could you post the code for `tableView: numberOfRowsInSection`  and `tableView: numberOfSections` ? Print `outcomes.count`.

Comment: post cellForRowAt function and structure of self.outcomes

Comment: I've added `tableView: numberOfRowsInSection` and `tableView: numberOfSections`

Comment: Is `datasource` and `delegate` of the table view connected? And – not related – use the dequeue API which returns a non-optional cell `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OutcomeTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! OutcomeTableViewCell`. A crash will reveal a design error.

Comment: yeah they are connected in videDidLoad() - table view is displaying data correctly - my goal is that when user clicks on filter button , I should get last month info and display it - thats where this things not working